# cannot quit while loop, (C++)?

Tags: c++, while-loop

here im trying a example from "C++ primer", however, it stuck at while loop. 
Here is my codes:

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    int sum =0 , value =0 ;    
    while (std::cin >> value)
    {
        sum += value;
    }

    std::cout << "sum is: " << sum << std::endl;
    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Please tell me how is it wrong, i will really appreciate that
Cheers
Eason.li

Comment: When do you want the loop to terminate?

Comment: That sort of loop is intended to read through the entire input stream. If you're using the keyboard as your input stream (as opposed to a file, for example) then press Ctrl+D to signal EOF. That will break out of the loop.

Comment: @Adam thx a lot, it helps, but shouldn't it quit while-loop as soon as the condition is not true is more?, BTW what is EOF?

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia   so my program will able to proceed to the next step

Comment: @libra Yes and the condition is not true any more when you have hit Ctrl+D (on Unix) or Ctrl+Z (on Windows). EOF is end of file. Your loop is written to loop until the end of file. I'm surprised that C++ primer doesn't explain this, that book has a good reputation. What did you think would make the loop condition not true?

Comment: @libra `cin >> value` returns an `istream` object (namely, `cin`). When put into a context where `cin` is supposed to be a boolean (like the condition of the while loop) then `cin` has an operator that returns true if the stream is in a valid state. That means no I/O errors and the End-Of-File (EOF) hasn't been reached. Once EOF is reached that operator returns false and your `while` loop terminates.

Comment: @john Thank you, now i get it, C++ primer explain this after another page, i think thats why i missed it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After entering a next value and pressing the Enter key you should press combination Ctrl+z (in Windows ) or Ctrl + d ( in Unix)

Comment: This character means the end of the stream.

Answer (score 1):

just put a condition to exit in your while clause

```
std::cin >> value;
while (value != 0)
{
    sum += value;
    std::cin >> value;
}
```

or, alternatively

```
do
{
    sum += value;
    std::cin >> value;
}while(value != 0);
```

Comment: if you use the `do while` just make sure your variables are initialized properly before the loop otherwise you may get some erroneous results. like in this example, make sure `value==0`

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a condition in the while loop

```
while (value !=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    bool input=true;

    int sum =0 , value =0 ;    
    while (input)
    {
        string choice;
        std::cout << "Enter Value to be added to sum"<<std::endl;
        std::cin>>value;  
        sum += value;

        std::cout<<"add another value?"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"Enter yes or no"<<std::endl;
        std::cin>>choice;
        if(choice=="yes")
        input=true;

        if(choice=="no")
        break;

    }

    std::cout << "sum is: " << sum << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```